# Ubicación de una celda a partir del valor de otra, con más de 2 columnas como condición en Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

Tengo problemas para ubicar una celda según las condiciones que les mostraré en el siguiente gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, necesito listar el nombre de la base de datos con mayor tamaño dentro de un determinado servidor. Hasta ahora solo he podido determinar el tamaño máximo de la base de datos por cada servidor (pero quiero el nombre también) con la siguiente fórmula que encontré en la red y que usa funciones matriciales: **{=MAX(SI(SERVIDOR="B",TAMAÑO))}**. He tratado de incluir esta construcción dentro de la función "BUSCAR" sin éxito, esta pide que el valor buscado sea la primera columna, y como verán mi orden de búsqueda va así: SERVIDOR-->TAMAÑO MAX --> BD.
De modo que el resultado ideal sería de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has intentado con `BUSCARV` en lugar de `BUSCAR`?

Comment: hola, si, con el buscarV, pero todo se resume a que es una búsqueda con más de una condición, de modo que la solución que le dí fue concatenar esas columnas "de más" en una columna auxiliar para que funcione como una sola y reordenar el orden de las columnas para que la función BuscarV funcione de forma correcta.

Comment: Sería bueno si pudieses agregar una respuesta explicando tu solución. De preferencia, indicar todas las funciones usadas para ello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo tenía la siguiente tabla resumen:

[image: Tablita Resumen]

La columna "TAMAÑO" corresponde a la base de datos más grande dentro del servidor A, B, C, etc. Y lo pude determinar con la fórmula  **{=MAX(SI(SERVIDOR="B",TAMAÑO))}** a partir del inventario (Data Principal), que es la siguiente:

[image: Tabla Inventario]

y lo que hace básicamente es determinar el máximo valor pero con la condición de que solo esté dentro del servidor "B" (como la fórmula de este ejemplo lo explica).

Pero tenía un problema para determinar la base de datos correspondiente a esa procedimiento. La función BUSCARV solo te permite un índice de búsqueda (una sola columna cómo condición), yo tenía 2 (SERVIDOR Y TAMAÑO) -- para --> encontrar BD Datos.

De modo que la solución fue concatenar (=A&9) (en otra hoja) las condiciones (SERVIDOR Y TAMAÑO) para que funcione como uno solo y la puse en la columna AUXILIAR de modo que me funcionara como índice de búsqueda de la siguiente manera:

[image: Tabla Inventario Modificado]

Ya no necesitaba calcular el máximo tamaño por que la primera tablita resumen ya guarda esa información, de modo que en la función buscarv solo tenía que concatenar los datos de esa tablita y la pondría como índice de búsqueda, esta la buscaría en la Tabla Inventario Modificada, Así: **=BUSCARV(servidor&tamaño**(tabla resumen)**,** **Matriz(AUXILIAR:BD)**(Inventario Modificado)**, 2** (Lo que estoy buscando)**, falso)** Y esa sería por consecuencia la BD con mayor tamaño. El resultado sería el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero se me haya entendido.

Saludos

Comment: Puedes marcar esta como la respuesta aceptada, @Fran, sugiero que lo hagas. Un saludo.